# docker community image login failing with network error

Tags: cloudify

## the problem

Trying to login using the browser:
[image: cloudify-community-image-failed-login]

Thanks in advance for any pointers on how to fix this issue.

## the steps taken

I started the community image with the following command:

`docker run --name cfy_manager_local -p 8080:80 cloudifyplatform/community-cloudify-manager-aio:latest`

Connected to the running container to verify **cloudify** status and network status:

`docker exec -it cfy_manager_local /bin/sh`

Executed:
`cfy status`

and got good status results

```
Retrieving manager services status... [ip=172.17.0.2]

Services:
+--------------------------------+--------+
|            service             | status |
+--------------------------------+--------+
| Webserver                      | Active |
| Cloudify Console               | Active |
| AMQP-Postgres                  | Active |
| Management Worker              | Active |
| Manager Rest-Service           | Active |
| Cloudify API                   | Active |
| Cloudify Execution Scheduler   | Active |
| PostgreSQL                     | Active |
| RabbitMQ                       | Active |
| Monitoring Service             | Active |
+--------------------------------+--------+
```

Tested network connectivity to the outside world:

`ping -c 4 emol.cl`

> Note: I'm located in WA state USA, so pinging a remote host in Chile, South America seems a good network test ;)

Got good results:

```
PING emol.cl (200.12.19.60) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 200.12.19.60 (200.12.19.60): icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=229 ms
64 bytes from 200.12.19.60 (200.12.19.60): icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=230 ms
64 bytes from 200.12.19.60 (200.12.19.60): icmp_seq=3 ttl=62 time=234 ms
64 bytes from 200.12.19.60 (200.12.19.60): icmp_seq=4 ttl=62 time=235 ms

--- emol.cl ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 4174ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 229.964/232.661/235.702/2.418 ms
```

Also, curling from inside the container:

`curl -L -w "\nHTTP status: %{http_code}\n" http://localhost`

returns:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Cloudify Console</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/console/style"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/console/static/images/favicon.png"></head><body><div id="app"></div><div class="splashPage active"><div class="logo"></div><div id="loader"></div></div><script defer="defer" src="/console/static/js/vendor.bundle.js"></script><script defer="defer" src="/console/static/js/main.bundle.js"></script></body></html>
HTTP status: 200
```

## Tried and expected

I tried to connect to the console from the browser, outside the container, and expected to be able to connect to the UI console. Instead, I got blocked by a survey.